# select from a column made of string array pyspark or python high order function multiple values

Tags: python, dataframe, arraylist, pyspark, higher-order-functions

i have  a table like this and i want to create a new column based on what is listed on the column
example

df.withcolumn('good',.when('java' or 'php' isin ['booksIntereste']).lit(1).otherwise(0))

[image: data table]

desired output when it contain java or php  get 1 else 0
[image: target]

Comment: Give us your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use a `Higher Order Function` - [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains) for this , additionally you can browse through [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/higher-order-functions-with-spark-3-1-7c6cf591beaa) article to understand more

#### Data Preparation

```
d = {
    'name':['James','Washington','Robert','Micheal'],
    'booksInterested':[['Java','C#','Python'],[],['PHP','Java'],['Java']]
}

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(d))

sparkDF.show()

+----------+------------------+
|      name|   booksInterested|
+----------+------------------+
|     James|[Java, C#, Python]|
|Washington|                []|
|    Robert|       [PHP, Java]|
|   Micheal|            [Java]|
+----------+------------------+
```

#### Array Contains

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('good',F.array_contains(F.col('booksInterested'), 'Java'))

+----------+------------------+-----+
|      name|   booksInterested| good|
+----------+------------------+-----+
|     James|[Java, C#, Python]| true|
|Washington|                []|false|
|    Robert|       [PHP, Java]| true|
|   Micheal|            [Java]| true|
+----------+------------------+-----+
```

#### ForAll Array Contains - Multiple

```
sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('good_multiple',F.forall(F.col('booksInterested'), lambda x: x.isin(['Java','Python','PHP'])))

sparkDF.show()

+----------+------------------+-----+-------------+
|      name|   booksInterested| good|good_multiple|
+----------+------------------+-----+-------------+
|     James|[Java, C#, Python]| true|        false|
|Washington|                []|false|         true|
|    Robert|       [PHP, Java]| true|         true|
|   Micheal|            [Java]| true|         true|
+----------+------------------+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: What if i have more than one argument say if it contain java or python or php then return true  because array_contains() takes 2 positional arguments ??

Comment: Updated the answer , demonstrating multiple pattern checks